# Customizing Metrics Keras

Tags: keras, metrics

I am trying to solve a regression problem with 3 outputs using Keras. I need to create a custom metric to compare the true and predicted values of each of those 3 variables and see if they are both in some range, if that happens, i count that as a success. I have tried something in the lines you can see below

```
Yclasses = 3 #Number of output classes
train_samples = 2 # Number of train samples in the batch
valid_samples = max(1,np.int(0.2*train_samples)) # Number of validation samples in the batch
cont = np.zeros((train_samples+valid_samples,Yclasses))
def nossa_metrica(y_true, y_pred):
  for l in range(0,y_true.shape[0]):
    for c in range(0,y_true.shape[0]):
      if c == 0:
        if y_true[l][c] <= 4000 and y_pred[l][c] <= 4000:
          cont[l][c] = 1
        elif (y_true[l][c] > 4000 and y_true[l][c] <= 8500) and (y_pred[l][c] > 4000 and y_pred[l][c] <= 8500):
          cont[l][c] = 1
        elif y_true[l][c] > 8500 and y_pred[l][c] > 8500:
          cont[l][c] = 1
      elif c == 1:
        if y_true[l][c] <= 1150 and y_pred[l][c] <= 1150:
          cont[l][c] = 1
        elif (y_true[l][c] > 1150 and y_true[l][c] <= 2300) and (y_pred[l][c] > 1150 and y_pred[l][c] <= 2300):
          cont[l][c] = 1
        elif y_true[l][c] > 2300 and y_pred[l][c] > 2300:
          cont[l][c] = 1
      elif c == 2:
        if (y_true[l][c] <= 0.075 and y_pred[l][c] <= 0.075) or (y_true[l][c] > 0.075 and y_pred[l][c] > 0.075):
          cont[l][c] = 1
  return np.sum(cont)/((train_samples+valid_samples)*Yclasses)
```

But, i am getting the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-1c70196ab01b> in <module>()
     68 
     69 #model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',verbose = 2,metrics=['binary_accuracy'])
---> 70 model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='adam',verbose = 2,metrics=[nossa_metrica])
     71 model.summary()
     72 

10 frames
<ipython-input-20-1c70196ab01b> in nossa_metrica(y_true, y_pred)
     15 print(cont)
     16 def nossa_metrica(y_true, y_pred):
---> 17   for l in range(0,y_true.shape[0]):
     18     for c in range(0,y_true.shape[0]):
     19       if c == 0:

TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

So, the error is related to my `for` loops? And i am not really sure how to use loops and conditions to define a custom metric. Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you pass in an empty batch, i.e. something of shape `(0, ...)`?

Comment: No, no empty batches.